# Show that if $T:E\times F\rightarrow G$ is a non-identically zero bilinear map, then there's two sequences with this property

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, uniform-continuity, bilinear-form

Let $E,F,G$ be normed spaces, and let $T:E\times F\rightarrow G$ be a non-identically zero bilinear map, then there are two sequences $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(v_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $E\times F$, with
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\|u_n-v_n\|_{E\times F} = 0
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\|T(u_n)-T(v_n)\|_{G} > 0.
$$

We are using the product norm:
$$
\|⋅\|_{ExF} = \max\{\|⋅\|_{E},\|⋅\|_{F}\}.
$$

Comment: What is $T(u_n)$ if $T$ is bilinear? Where is the other argument?

Comment: $u_n$ is in $E \times F$ so $u_n = (e_n,f_n)$ where $e_n\in E$ and $f_n\in F$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $T(e,f)\ne0$ then define $u_n = n (e,f)$, $v_n=(n+\frac1n)(e,f)$.

This basically reduces everything to $E=F=G=\mathbb R$: the claim follows since $\|u_n-v_n\| = \frac1n\|(e,f)\|$ and $\|T(u_n)-T(v_n)\|=\|T(e,f)\|\cdot (2  + \frac1{n^2})$.